# How to execute xarray's open_dataset() in a parallel function?

Tags: python, parallel-processing, multiprocessing, python-xarray

**Context:** I have a function `Looper` that opens a `netcdf` file with `xarray` and makes some operation with it. I want to parallelize it.

**Problem:** My function starts running in parallel, but stops once it hits the `xr.open_dataset()` part of it.

**Question:** How can I parallelize my code to make it open several datasets in parallel ? I don't want to use dask of `xr.open_mfdataset` because the function I work with in reality does other things than just opening datasets, and `mfdataset` would not be appropriate.

I created a simple function that just opens a dataset. However, when I run it in parallel only the 1st statement (`1`) is printed, hinting that the function stops along the way.

**Example:**

```
# Function to create datasets

def create_random_netcdf(filename):
data = np.random.rand(10, 20)  # Example random data
times = pd.date_range(start='2023-08-01', periods=10, freq='D')

    da = xr.DataArray(data, dims=['time', 'space'], coords={'time': times})
    
    ds = xr.Dataset({'random_data': da})
    
    ds.to_netcdf(filename)

# Function to run in parallel

def looper(filename, number):
print('1')
ds = xr.open_dataset(filename)
\# Simulate some processing on the dataset
ds\["data"\] = ds\["data"\] \* number
print('2')
return ds

# Create a folder to store the NetCDF files

output_folder = Path('netcdf_files')
output_folder.mkdir(exist_ok=True)

# Create 10 NetCDF files with random data

filepaths = \[\]
for i in range(10):
filename = output_folder / f'random_data\_{i}.nc'
create_random_netcdf(filename)
filepaths.append(filename)

# Run Looper in parallel

if __name__ == '__main__':

    # multiprocessing pool object
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=4)
    
    # Create tuple inputs
    inputs = [(file, number) for file, number in zip(filepaths, range(10))]
    
    # Unpack each input tuple and pass to looper function
    results = []
    for input_tuple in inputs:
        pool.apply_async(looper, input_tuple)
        
    
    # Close the pool and wait for all processes to complete
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
```